# Via Rail Canada: What are the different booking classes?

Tags: trains, canada, via-rail

Today, I tried to book a seat in a train on the [Via Rail Canada Homepage](http://www.viarail.ca/en).

There are 6 different booking classes:

```
SuperSaver
Discounted
Regular
```

for both Economy and Business. While I can imagine the difference between Economy and Business, I'm unsure what the other 3 booking classes are indicating. Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: I think it's how far in advance you have to book them, how flexible they are for changes etc, BICBW

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the details on the [Compare Fares page](http://www.viarail.ca/en/fares/compare-fares) if you expand a route. It's all about how changeable they are, and how far in advance you have to book them

The only real difference it looks like between Business and Economy is there's no Business Escape ticket, and the cheapest business tickets are less changeable.

For **Economy**:

- Escape

  - Minimum 4 day advanced purchase
  - Non-refundable, Non-exchangeable
- Supersaver

  - Minimum 3 days advanced purchase
  - Refundable and exchangeable for 50% service charge (A minimum service charge fee of $20 will be applied.)
- Discounted

  - Minimum 1 day advanced purchase
  - Refundable and exchangeable for 25% of the fare (minimum $20)
- Regular

  - Available on the day
  - Refundable and exchangeable (No service charge)

For **Business**:

- Supersaver

  - Minimum 3 days advanced purchase
  - Non-refundable, Non-exchangeable
- Discounted

  - Minimum 1 day advanced purchase, Refundable and exchangeable ($25 service charge)
- Regular

  - Available on the day
  - Refundable and exchangeable (No service charge)