# Is the VIA rail "discounted fare" for certain categories, or can anyone travel on this?

Tags: trains, canada

For the VIA rail "discounted fare", is this a simple advance limited-flexibility booking category like for airlines, or is this a fare only available to particular categories such as youth, students, seniors, etc.?

I'm unsure because [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/8268/2509) states it's just a limited-flexibility thing, but its reference is a broken link; on the other hand, [this VIA rail page on discounts](http://www.viarail.ca/en/fares-and-packages/discounts) specifically mentions youths, seniors, and others.

The exact category of the ticket is "upper berth - discounted fare".

Comment: It is confusing, I agree. When booking a cabin for 2 the term "discounted" gives you the single-occupancy-rate. Best to ask VIA directly they are rather quick in answering e-mails. Bon voyage!

Answer (score 3):

I spent over a year travelling back and forth on VIA trains on a regular basis for work. The discounted fare is available for anyone based on availability and any further discounts (senior, student, etc.) are separate. However, my experience is solely in the Quebec-Windsor corridor, so it's possible things are different elsewhere.